# On windows, powershell autocompletes the path, but node doesn't know how to use the path

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell

[image]

this happens whenever a path is sent in like this (autocompleted with a leading `.\`).

removing the leading `.\` makes it work...

halp?

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: latest. happened on 5 and now 7